# How to pass in parameters when use resource service?

Tags: angularjs

A very rookie-ish question:

I'm trying to build resource object using factory method:

```
.factory('Magazines', [function ($resource) {

    var url = document.URL;
    var urlArray = url.split("/");
    var organId = urlArray[urlArray.length-1];

    return $resource('http://localhost/ci/api/magazines/:id', {
        loginID : organEntity,
        password : organCommpassword,
        id : organId
    });
  }])
```

This method is easy because all params are predefined, organEntity and organCommpassword are defined inside  tag.

Now for a different resource object, I need to pass in parameter when the factory is called.

I imagine the calling code of this resource object should look like:

```
.controller('ResrouceCtrl', function($scope, Magazines) {
      $scope.magazines = Magazines.query();
});
```

I know query() method can add parameters: `Magazines.query(params, successcb, errorcb);`

I wonder if I just pass in parameters, can I get the parameter at the factory? How to specify such passed in parameters in the factory method?

For example, now suppose I cannot get organId from url anymore, I need to pass it in from my controller, how to receive organId within the factory method?

---

Here is my resource js:

```
.factory('MagComments', function ($resource) {


    return $resource('http://localhost/dooleystand/ci/api/magCommenct/:id', {
      loginID : organEntity,
      password : organCommpassword,
      id : '@magId' //pass in param using @ syntax
    });
  })
```

Here is my controller:

```
$scope.magComments = MagComments.query({magId : 1});
```

I tried to pass in the parameter, but it causes an error

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you are doing some more code might be helpful. Why would it matter where you got the organId from? I would just pass the value into the .query() method when the controller calls it though, as you said already. The factory is only ever called once in your application, so "Magazines" is a singleton.

Comment: So I can just pass in the parameters from my controller through .query() and just use it in the factory?

Comment: I don't think you are clear on what the factory does. The factory creates an object which is passed to your controller when you specify it depends on "Magazines" in the constructor function. So the resource you returned *is* Magazines in your controller and it works just like the documentation says it does. Or are you saying you want to use different defaults for a specific controller that I can show you but I would think just calling the query with "params" should work fine for your situation.

Comment: @ChrisNicola Sorry. I run into some problems with passing in parameters. My console tells me `magId is not defined`. Is my pass-in method wrong?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think I see your problem, you need to use the `@` syntax to define parameters you will pass in this way, also I'm not sure what loginID or password are doing you don't seem to define them anywhere and they are not being used as URL parameters so are they being sent as query parameters?

This is what I can suggest based on what I see so far:

```
.factory('MagComments', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost/dooleystand/ci/api/magCommenct/:id', {
      loginID : organEntity,
      password : organCommpassword,
      id : '@magId'
    });
  })
```

The `@magId` string will tell the resource to replace `:id` with the property `magId` on the object you pass it as parameters.

I'd suggest reading over [the documentation here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) (I know it's a bit opaque) very carefully and looking at the examples towards the end, this should help a lot.

Comment: Haha, don't worry about that loginID and password. They are defined within `<script></script>` in HTML. Thank you! I'll read the document more carefully!

Comment: So they are global variables or something?

Comment: giving this a thumbs up not only because it solved my problem, but also bc you said to look at the docs... which should always be the first thing I do! hahaha

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you to use `provider`. 
Provide is good when you want to configure it first before to use (against Service/Factory)

Something like:

```
.provider('Magazines', function() {

    this.url = '/';
    this.urlArray = '/';
    this.organId = 'Default';

    this.$get = function() {
        var url = this.url;
        var urlArray = this.urlArray;
        var organId = this.organId;

        return {
            invoke: function() {
                return ......
            }
        }
    };

    this.setUrl  = function(url) {
        this.url = url;
    };

   this.setUrlArray  = function(urlArray) {
        this.urlArray = urlArray;
    };

    this.setOrganId  = function(organId) {
        this.organId = organId;
    };
});

.config(function(MagazinesProvider){
    MagazinesProvider.setUrl('...');
    MagazinesProvider.setUrlArray('...');
    MagazinesProvider.setOrganId('...');
});
```

And now controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, Magazines) {        

        Magazines.invoke();

       ....

}
```