# angularjs error on server callback

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm making a call to the server using resource and when I go to the base URL of

/viewEvent

It works fine. I receive all the database entries. However, when I go to

/viewEvent/1234

where 1234 is the eventID

I get a *undefined is not a function* and this is a crash from within angular. Stack trace is

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at copy (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/angular/angular.js:593:21)
at http://localhost:8000/js/lib/angular/angular-resource.js:410:19
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/angular/angular.js:6846:59)
at http://localhost:8000/js/lib/angular/angular.js:6883:26
at Object.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/angular/angular.js:8057:28)
at Object.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/angular/angular.js:7922:25)
at Object.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/angular/angular.js:8143:24)
at done (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/angular/angular.js:9170:20)
at completeRequest (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/angular/angular.js:9333:7)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange   (http://localhost:8000/js/lib/angular/angular.js:9303:11) angular.js:575
```

When I examine the server, the request was made correctly. I can see that it got 1234 and it pulls the correct entry from the mongo database.

This is the controller logic

```
.controller("viewEventsController", ["$scope", 'EventService', '$location', function($scope, EventService, $location){

    var path = $location.path().split('/');
    var pathSize = path.length;
    $scope.events = [];

    if(pathSize === 2){
        console.log("No event ID");

        $scope.events = EventService.query();

    }
    else{
        console.log("Event ID specified");
        EventService.get({"eventID": path[pathSize - 1]}, function(data){
            //$scope.events.push(data);
            console.log(data);
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}]);
```

and the service logic

```
service.factory('EventService', function($resource){
    return $resource('api/viewEvent/:eventID');
});
```

It never makes it back to the controller so I'm "confident" it's not that. (watch it be that)

Comment: Check out this answer for proper use of passing parameters into $resource (eventID). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365714/how-to-pass-in-parameters-when-use-resource-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the best way, but I got it working by doing

In service:

```
service.factory('EventService', function($resource){
    return $resource('api/viewEvent/:eventID',
        {eventID:"@eventID"},
        {
            'getSingleEvent': {
            url: "api/viewEvent/:eventID",
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true
           }
        }
    );
```

controller

```
var path = $location.path().split('/');
var pathSize = path.length;

EventService.getSingleEvent({"eventID":path[pathSize - 1]}, function(result){
        $scope.updateEvent();
    });
```

Server

```
routes = require('./routes')
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/api/viewEvent/:eventID', routes.viewEvent);
```

and in the routes directory I have a js file with

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'eventApp');
var eventSchema = require('../models/createEvent.js').eventSchema;
var event = db.model('events', eventSchema);

exports.viewEvent = function(req, res){

console.log(req.params.eventID);

if(req.params.eventID) {
    event.find({"_id": req.params.eventID}, function (error, events) {
        console.log(events);
        res.send(events);
    });
}
else{
    event.find({}, function (error, events) {
        console.log(events);
        res.send(events);
    })
}
};
```