# Angularjs, how to put in a variable in a $resource get-request

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to put a variable in a get request in Angularjs.

Here is a working code:

```
app.controller("CustomerDetailController", [
    "$scope","$routeParams","$resource",
    function($scope , $routeParams , $resource) {

        var Customer = $resource('/customers/400.json');

        $scope.customer = Customer.get();

    }
]);
```

As you can see, the number 400 is hardcoded in the url in $resource. Now, I want to replace it with a variable. I tried to follow the documentation on [angular $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) , but I made an error somewhere. Here is what I tried:

```
app.controller("CustomerDetailController", [
    "$scope","$routeParams","$resource",
    function($scope , $routeParams , $resource) {

        var Customer = $resource('/customers/:customerId.json', {customerId: '@id'});

        $scope.customer = Customer.get({customerId: 400});

    }
]);
```

Can someone spot the mistake?

EDIT: I added some alerts, to check, where errors arise:

```
    alert("1. Ajax Call Initiated!"); //gets called
    var customerId = 400;


    alert("2. Ajax Call Initiated!"); //gets called

    var Customer = $resource('/customers/:customerId.json', {customerId: '@id'});

    $scope.customer = Customer.get({customerId: 400});

    alert("3. Ajax Call Initiated!"); // This alert is NOT called
```

EDIT 2:

The console prints this error:

Error: encodeUriSegment is not a function ...

Edit 3: Turns out, my angular components didn't have the same versions.

Comment: see if this solves your issue :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365714/how-to-pass-in-parameters-when-use-resource-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Problem were insconsistent angular modules (1.5.9 vs. 1.6)

```
app.controller("CustomerDetailController", [
    "$scope","$routeParams","$resource",
    function($scope , $routeParams , $resource) {

        var Customer = $resource('/customers/:customerId.json', {customerId: '@id'});

        Customer.get({customerId: 400}, function(customer, responseHeader){
           $scope.customer = customer;
        });

    }
]);
```

Comment: It is not working for me. Do you need any more information? In the view, instead of the name I get: {{customer.first_name}}

Comment: sorry, haven seen that you missed using the callback safely. updated code

Comment: Is the api being called? Is the response a valid JSON response?

Comment: My first blockcode works. But there, the link is hardcoded. I want to replace 400 with a variable, so 400 or any number can be put in.

Comment: Does the second at least call the api?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130474/discussion-between-campino2k-and-metaphysiker).